# Cannot install Apache2 module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, passenger

I am trying to install Apache2 module for Ruby on rails using
    passenger-install-apache2-module

However,it returns a error during compiling and installing Apache2 module returning

```
rm -rf buildout/cache
rm -rf buildout/common/libboost_oxt.a buildout/common/libboost_oxt
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/wide_posix_api.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/cpp_regex_traits.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/tss_null.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/future.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/thread.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/posix_api.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/once_atomic.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/error_code.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/instances.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_raw_buffer.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/once.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/winstances.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/c_regex_traits.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/static_mutex.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/cregex.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/lockpool.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/wc_regex_traits.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_traits_defaults.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/boost/regex_debug.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt/implementation.o': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `buildout/common/libboost_oxt/oxt/system_calls.o': Permission denied
rake aborted!
```

How can I avoid this error and install apache2 module?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You don't have permission to remove the file. Perhaps run it as su.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Comment: It returns sudo: passenger-install-apache2-module: command not found

Comment: Can you run "gem environment" and copy the output of line that says: – EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: ......

Comment: Read this section from the official Phusion Passenger documentation to learn how to solve the "command not found" problem: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_i_get_command_not_found_when_running_a_phusion_passenger_command_through_sudo